# React conditional rendering isn't working on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to uncheck input if the item status is false. it's working fine in my localhost. But it's not working after deploying to the server.

```html
{data.map((item) => (
  <tr key={item.id}>
  <td>{item.name}</td>
  <td>{item.body.slice(0, 90)}</td>
  <td>
      {item.status === 1 ?
          <Form.Check
              type="switch"
              id="custom-switch"
              checked
          /> :
          <Form.Check
              type="switch"
              id="custom-switch"
          />
  }
  </td>
  <td>{item.author.username}</td>
  <td>
      <Link to={`/admin/categories/view/${item.id}`} style={{ paddingRight: "12px" }}> <FaEye
          style={{ fontSize: "22px", color: "#071337", cursor: "pointer" }} /></Link>
      <span onClick={() => deleteHandler(item.id)} style={{ paddingRight: "12px" }}><TiDelete
          style={{ fontSize: "22px", color: "#c0392b", cursor: "pointer" }} /></span>
      <Link to={`/admin/categories/edit/${item.id}`} style={{ paddingRight: "12px" }}> <FaEdit
          style={{ fontSize: "22px", color: "#f39c12", cursor: "pointer" }} /></Link>
  </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's not enough to understand the issue, please supply the code that executes after triggering the change of the status (toggle) and the update server's call

Comment: What have been your steps to debug the problem? If it works locally but not on the server, maybe the data is different? For example the status might be a string... I suggest evaluating what the items actually contain.

Comment: {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "type": "category",
      "name": "sds",
      "img_path": "images/category/1644690998-slider_five.jpg",
      "body": "sdsd",
      "status": 1,
      "slug": "sds",
      "products": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
this is my json data, I want to checked radio button if data status is true. its working on my localhost.

Comment: your should log all your items and will see your status is not 1. then go on and check why it is not 1. may be overwritten somewhere?